# How to uninstall Citrix Receiver package with confirmation

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-uninstall

I am trying to run a command line task on a HP thin Client to uninstall citrix receiver.

The task runs the below command on the client.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove -y icaclient-term
```

It shows it has completed successfully but when I check I can see the receiver is still installed.

On x-terminal I can successfully uninstall by just running

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove icaclient-term
```

What is the correct command to uninstall with a confirmation when prompted for `y/n`?

Comment: Like this `sudo apt-get --purge remove -y icaclient-term` so I would assume you have a different issue. Is the receiver inactive/stopped when uninstalling? You can't remove it when it is still running.

Comment: it is inactive when I am running the command task. I just tried manually running sudo apt-get --purge remove -y icaclient-term and it uninstalled with out any prompts for y/n. Just doesn't seem to work when I send the command task.

Comment: You added a `-y` to not be asked prompts (and answer Yes to prompts)? but want the prompts you told it not to ask you?

Comment: I entred Y to answer yes for the promtp to uninstall the package. I think I found the issue, I needed to run a command fsunlock first, it then uninstalled the ica client from the looks.

Comment: ah I knew that :-X fsunlock ofcourse

Comment: @Rinzwind seems like OP never added the answer, so the spot is still up for grabs...

Answer (score 2):

Use the below command to uninstall:

```
sudo apt remove icaclient && sudo apt purge icaclient
```

Comment: great, helps a lot. I only used "sudo apt purge icaclient". For my understanding this comprises the "remove" process. Works fine!